# Managed properties not available SharePoint on prem refiners

Tags: managed-property, refiner

I have added following Managed Properties and mapped to it's crawled properties. Any idea why they dont show up in the refiner? I have refinable, sort, searchable all set to true.

```
Region - Text
RegionNumber - Text
Country - Managed Metadata
ProductType - Text
CustomerNumber - Text
CustomerName - Text
```

Do I have to use OOTB refinable properties for on premise sharepoint like this article suggests. http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/11/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score -1):

These are working now after performing a full crawl.